# My node app cant find a module called '/app/bin/www' but it can run locally how do i fix this?

Tags: node.js, heroku

```
2017-07-16T19:13:20.904238+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! loc8r@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2017-07-16T19:13:20.904447+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-07-16T19:13:20.904703+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-07-16T19:13:20.905123+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-07-16T19:13:20.904921+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the loc8r@0.0.0 start script.
2017-07-16T19:13:20.906642+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-16T19:13:20.906961+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-07-16T19:13:20.907157+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-07-16T19_13_20_897Z-debug.log
2017-07-16T19:13:21.021614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-07-16T19:13:21.037719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-07-16T19:13:21.036675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-16T19:13:22.679613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-07-16T19:13:24.568608+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-16T19:13:24.568624+00:00 app[web.1]: > loc8r@0.0.0 start /app
2017-07-16T19:13:24.568625+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2017-07-16T19:13:24.568625+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688256+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:471
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688258+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688258+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688259+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688260+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/bin/www'
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688261+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688261+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688263+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688262+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688268+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
2017-07-16T19:13:24.688269+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
2017-07-16T19:13:24.702854+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-07-16T19:13:24.703078+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2017-07-16T19:13:24.703406+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-07-16T19:13:24.703247+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! loc8r@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2017-07-16T19:13:24.703555+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-07-16T19:13:24.703684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the loc8r@0.0.0 start script.
2017-07-16T19:13:24.704576+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-16T19:13:24.703810+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-07-16T19:13:24.704866+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-07-16T19_13_24_697Z-debug.log
2017-07-16T19:13:24.704758+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-07-16T19:13:24.772353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-16T19:13:24.762213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

How do i fix it because it says it cant find '/app/bin/www' but this was the skeleton for an express application.I made sure to not include the node_modules and this application works locally but not when i deploy it through heroku.

Comment: how is your folder structure and package.json?

Comment: We would need a code sample and the folder structure if you can, it would help :)

Comment: set the commad that runs your app in a Procfile. And you should push node_modules to your remote server

Comment: what do you need me to do and what code sample do you need?